# Ajax running function inside my Class prototype?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function MyClass() {
    this.test = function () {
        return 'foo';
    }
}
MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function (data) {
    alert(data.name);
}
var newClass = new MyClass();
setTimeout(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html/',
        data: newClass,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('in success callback');
            console.log('received data: ' + data);
        }
    });
}, 3000);
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Why does ajax trigger `newClass.myMethod`? because of JSON parsing? how to avoid this error?

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CLpg/)

Comment: What data do you expect to be sent via the AJAX call?

Comment: @RocketHazmat, I use this Class in different things. I did not think about using that method/function when I passed it to jQuery's Ajax, but the error surprised me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because jQuery uses `jQuery.param` internally on the data, if you look at the source of `jQuery.param` it invokes all the functions and uses the result as data

So, I don't know what you want to do to get around it, but atleast you know what it is

`jQuery.ajax` part of source that is calling `jQuery.param`

```
// Convert data if not already a string
if (s.data && s.processData && typeof s.data !== "string") {
    s.data = jQuery.param(s.data, s.traditional);
}
```

`jQuery.param` part of source that calls function:

```
  var prefix, s = [],
        add = function (key, value) {
        // => If value is a function, invoke it and return its value
        value = jQuery.isFunction(value) ? value() : (value == null ? "" : value);
        s[s.length] = encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
    };
```

**Update:**

You can use `processData: false` to disable data processing, yet that means you will need to process your data manually like so

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/html/',
    data: JSON.stringify(newClass), // pass the processed string
    processData: false,  // and add this 
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('in success callback');
        console.log('received data: ' + data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your demo just sends `[object Object]` as the data in the AJAX call.

Comment: @RocketHazmat other than that, there doesn't seem to be any way to avoid this, it looks like you either have data processing or you don't, so he'll have to do it manually

Comment: Yeah.  That's why I asked in the comments "what data do you expect to be sent via the AJAX call"?